# wildcards in keep in a data step

Tags: sas

is it possible to use wildcards in the `keep` of a data step? I want to do the following (left join of A on B keeping variables x and y and all variables starting with a):

```
data C;
    merge A(in=a)
          B(keep= x y var* in=b);
    by x y;
    if a;
run;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use `:`.

```
data C;
    merge A(in=a)
          B(keep=x y a: in=b);
    by x y;
    if a;
run;
```

(It's not a good idea to say `in=a` if you have a variable named `a`.)

If you have variables with sequential numbers, like `a1`, `a2`, ..., `aN`, you can write `a1-aN`. And if you want a set of adjacent columns (say `varX`, `varY`, and `varZ` are physically adjacent in the data set), you can say `varX--varZ`. The difference between these two examples is just whether you use one dash or two.

Comment: BTW, can I use regexp or similar to select column names ?

Comment: Not directly.  You can through a separate step; for example, you have dictionary.columns which is the table containing all column names and table names in the current session.  You can run queries in SQL against it, or using the SAS equivalent sashelp.vcolumn, run SAS datasteps against it.  Then store the results in a macro variable and use that macro variable in an actual keep step.